# Why an cursor opened for a select with ORDER by does not reflect updates to the subsequent table

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have set this little example of a strange behavior

```
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    create table #tmp
    (id int identity (1,1),
    value int);

    insert into #tmp (value) values(10);
    insert into #tmp (value) values(20);
    insert into #tmp (value) values(30);

    select * from #tmp;

    declare @tmp_id int, @tmp_value int;
    declare tmpCursor cursor for 
    select t.id, t.value from #tmp t
    --order by t.id;

    open tmpCursor;

    fetch next from tmpCursor into @tmp_id, @tmp_value;

    while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    begin
        print 'ID: '+cast(@tmp_id as nvarchar(max));

        if (@tmp_id = 1 or @tmp_id = 2)
            insert into #tmp (value)
            values(@tmp_value * 10);

        fetch next from tmpCursor into @tmp_id, @tmp_value;
    end

    close tmpCursor;
    deallocate tmpCursor;

    select * from #tmp;
    drop table #tmp;
```

We can observe with the help of `print` how the cursors parses even the new rows in the `#tmp` table. However if we uncomment the `order by t.id` in the cursor declaration - the new rows are not parsed.

Is this an intended behavior ?

Comment: Not all execution plan operators can support dynamic cursors. See the section "Dynamic cursor support" in [Properties of Iterators](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/craigfr/archive/2006/06/19/637048.aspx). If you change the definition to `id int identity (1,1) primary key` so that an index exists and the sort is avoided you'll probably get a dynamic cursor.

Comment: My true intent was to find out if there is a possibility to keep the dynamic behavior and still have the order by. All answers are great, now I have the direction to further look into.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The behavior you see is rather subtle.  By default, cursors in SQL Server are dynamic, so you would expect to see changes.  However, buried in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180169.aspx) is this line:

> SQL Server implicitly converts the cursor to another type if clauses
>   in select_statement conflict with the functionality of the requested
>   cursor type.

When you include the `order by`, SQL Server reads all the data and turns it into a temporary table for sorting.  In this process, SQL Server must also change the type of cursor from dynamic to static.  This is not particularly well documented, but you can readily see the behavior.

Comment: Just to add if the cursor declaration is changed to `declare tmpCursor cursor type_warning ... ` then it does give a message `The created cursor is not of the requested type.`

Answer (score 5):

You can use the sp_describe_cursor stored procedure to view the metadata of the cursor.  Doing so on your example shows the following:

ORDER BY included:

**model** = Insensitive (or static), **concurrency** = Read-Only

ORDER BY excluded:

**model** = Dynamic, **concurrency** = Optimistic

Source: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173806(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 2):

I think that by putting in an ORDER BY clause it then forces the CURSOR to be a STATIC CURSOR whereas without it defaults to DYNAMIC.